# $\ln 2$ partial sums

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> $$[*] \ \ \ \ln(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} ((x-1)^k/k)$$

And from Leibniz we have

> $$ |S - Sn| \le a_{n+1}$$

where $Sn$ is partial sum.

And I have that exercise:

> To calculate $\ln(2)$ using $[*]$ with error less than
>   $\frac{1}{2}*10^{-6}$ we have to use $a > 2000,000$. Show that using
>   $\ln(e(2/e))$ can shorten it significantly.

I can't understand how does it help with shortening calculations. Could you help me?

Comment: You know that $\ln (x\cdot y) = \ln x + \ln y$ for $x,y > 0$? And what $\ln e$ is?

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\ln{2} = \ln{(e \frac{2}{e})} = \ln{e} + \ln\frac{2}{e} = 1 + \ln{\frac{2}{e}}$$

Now $2/e$ is much closer to $1$ than $2$ is, and so the quantity $|2/e - 1|^k$ shrinks quite quickly; for we see that

$$|a_{n + 1}| = \frac{1}{k} \left(1 - \frac{2}{e}\right)^k \approx \frac{1}{k \cdot 4^k}$$ In particular, taking $k = 10$, we already have error. on the order of 
2 \cdot 10^{-7}$.

Comment: Thanks man. I guess it's to late for me to do the thinking today.